# Execute SwingWorker in a for loop

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I want to acquire images from a scanner and place them in a HashMap with names in a certain order of sequence  performed by SwingWorker Class called ScanningService. I want to use a for loop to acquire another image after the first is complete using the same device.  `scan.getImage()` returns the scanned image once done. The `sc` parameter is a scanner object.  Maybe someone can offer me an implementation with Executor or Timer because my trials have not borne any fruits.

```
    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
        lblMessage.setText("Scan Next Image: ");
        scan = new ScanningService(sc);
        scan.execute();
        scan.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(StateValue.DONE == scan.getState()){

                    lblImagePreview.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scan.getImage()));
                    //logic for name in order of sequence
                    imageList.put<imagename, scan.getImage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'd probably put the loop inside the `SwingWorker` as, presumably, you can only scan one document at a time...

Comment: what's going wrong? the snippet looks fine so far ... would put the execute at the end, though, just to be be sure that the worker isn't ready before we added the listener :-)

Answer (score 1):

- [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) is designated to run only once, then after you have to invoke a new instance
- [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) isn't proper for loading an images, nor on some period
- have look `Runnable#Thread`, output to the Swing GUI must be wrapper in `invokeLater()`
- all changes to the  Swing GUI must be done on `EventDispatchThrea`d, you have look at [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: 1) OP is doing exactly what you suggest b) what do you mean? c) why? A swingworker abstracts away all the dirty details d) correct, but that's exactly what the OP is already doing (by means of listening to the swingworker state change)

Comment: @kleopatra my never ending story continue... 1. `Runnable#Thread` is still the better choice, 2. `Runnable#Thread` doesn't required for most methods wrapping into `invokeLater` safer is use that, 3. not there are a few code example that required `invokeLater` from `SwingWorkers` methods`publish`, `process` and `done` with logics description by real Swing gurus (-:I excluding my person, I'm only contributor with lots of posts an poor upvoting score:-), 4. never to use that for production code, 5. for enjoy or learning is `SwingWorkers` very usefull `APIs`, 6. why confusing OP nothing else

Comment: shaking head in full disagreement ... never ending story indeed ;-) Would like to see a _required invokeLater_ in the worker's methods that run on the EDT.

Comment: @kleopatra shaking head in full disagreement ... never ending story indeed ;-), then why, no reason to continue ..., sorry